# How to simplify boolean expression?

Tags: logic, proof-techniques, boolean-algebra

I am having trouble simplifying logical expressions to a much simpler form, can someone provide me some insight on how to approach the problem?

Let's assume i have the following expression: $ABCD + A\bar{B}CD$.

I am aware of the De Morgan's law, but not sure how to apply them in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: Define "simpler form"... what is "simple" usually depends quite a bit on intended use, and moreover has strong "taste" components...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of simplification are you looking for ?

In the case you've given, $ABCD+A\bar{B}CD= ACD(B+\bar{B}) = ACD $.

In any case, [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html) is a set of laws of Boolean algebra that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with an expression in [canonical normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form), you can simplify it by applying normal algebraic methods `ABCD + ABbarCD = ABCD(1 + bar) = ABCD` or in less obvious cases using a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: The Quine-McCluskey algorithm is more efficient than Karnaugh maps if you want to implement it as a program.